# $2×2 $ real symmetric matrix full classification

Tags: optimization, determinant, quadratic-forms, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix}$$ all real numbers.

I know that

- If $\operatorname{det}(A) > 0$ then $A$ is positive definite if $a > 0$ and negative definite if $a < 0$.
- If $\operatorname{det}(A) < 0$ then $A$ is indefinite.
- If $ \operatorname{det}(A) = 0 $ and $ a > 0 $, then $ A $ is positive semidefinite.
- If $ \operatorname{det}(A) = 0 $ and $ a < 0 $, then $ A $ is negative semidefinite.
- If $ \operatorname{det}(A) = 0 $, $ a = 0 $, and $c>0$ then $ A$ is positive semidefinite.
- If $ \operatorname{det}(A) = 0 $, $ a = 0 $, and $c<0$ then $ A$ is negative semidefinite.
- If $ \operatorname{det}(A) = 0 $, $ a = 0 $, and $c=0$ then $ A$ is the zero matrix and then is positive semidefinite and negative semidefinite.

Is this classification correct and complete?
Why this classification is not in every textbook about quadratic forms?

Comment: If $\det A = 0$ and $a = 0$, we have $0 = ac - b^2 = -b^2$, hence $b = 0$. Now, the classification just depends on $\operatorname{sgn}(c)$.

Comment: Added your contribution.

Comment: It is not in every textbook since there is a more general classification that works in any dimension

Comment: Which one? Eigenvalues?

Answer (score 2):

$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}x+y&z\\z&x-y\end{array}\right]$ is also an interesting parameterization, with the cone of revolution  $x>\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$ visualizing the positive definite matrices, and so on. Another advandage is the invariance of the classification by the rotations around the $Ox$ axis, and a geometrical view of the space of symmetric matrices of order 2. .

Comment: Thanks, I will think about your comment.